# NASM Syscall write with stack src dont work :/

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, system-calls

I have written a small syscall function in NASM that works so far.

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
  mov rcx, text
  mov rdx, 7
  mov rbx, 1
  mov rax, 4
  int 0x80
  mov rax, 1
  mov rbx, 0
  int 0x80
  text:
  db "ABCDEFG",0x0a
```

This give me the output : ABCDEFG

When i use this way:

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
  mov rcx, 0x0a47464544434241
  push rcx
  mov rcx, rsp
  mov rdx, 7
  mov rbx, 1
  mov rax, 4
  int 0x80
  mov rax, 1
  mov rbx, 0
  int 0x80
```

This version prints nothing :(
Can anyone tell me exactly why this is?
I have already spent a few hours in the debugger but without success.

Comment: I hope you got as far in the debugger or `strace` as noticing that your system calls returned `-EFAULT` (bad pointer), when you passed a 64-bit (stack) pointer to the 32-bit ABI.

Comment: Hi, exactly this "EFAULT" error I get :/
Can you tell me exactly how to work around this or why this problem occurs exactly?

I am still a bit new in the field.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Look at the "duplicate" link at the top of this page. I already wrote a whole giant answer about exactly what's going on here.